# array in descending order doesn't work in C

Tags: c

```
      #include <stdio.h>

      int main()

      {
        int a[100],i,n,j,p;
        printf("Enter number of elements:\n ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("Enter array:\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
          scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
          for(j=1;j<n;j++)
          {
            if(a[i]>a[j])
            {
              p=a[j];
              a[j]=a[i];
              a[i]=p;
            }
          }
        }
        printf("The array looks :\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
          printf("%d\t",a[i]);
        }
          return 0;
      }
```

This works smooth except the smallest element is still the first :( When I run it it has no errors, but when I enter numbers for ex. 1,2,3,4,5 and it turns out 1 5 4 3 2.

Comment: this looks like bubble sort algorithm. why you don't look at pseudocode to see how it should work `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort`

Comment: btw you **should** initialized `j = i + 1` instead of 1.

Comment: Some commenters have suggested that this is an [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) or a [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort); it is actually a [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), with the bug (noted below) that `j` should be initialized to `i+1`, and that this will sort in ascending, not descending order.

Comment: @user295691 yes its selection sort. But OP interested to know why above code not working.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan fair enough.  I was going to respond with a "why it isn't working" in this comment, but it was too long, so I just posted it as an answer below.  The fix you suggest, initializing `j = i + 1`, is sufficient (as I noted) to fix the algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Please be more organized with your code!

Here is a neater-looking version of it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

void selectionSort(int a[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (a[i] > a[j])
                swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
}

main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int a[n], i;
    printf("Enter the array:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    selectionSort(a, n);

    printf("The array looks like this:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your inner "for" loop as follows:

```
      for(j=1;j<(n-i) ;j++)
      {
        if(a[j-1]<a[j])
        {
          p=a[j-1];
          a[j-1]=a[j];
          a[j]=p;
        }
```

This allows you to traverse your entire array "n" times as needed to bump the greater number between two consecutive array elements down 1 until the entire list is sorted.  So using your example of 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 with n = 5, the "snap shots" of the array after the inner for loop is executed are [51234], [54123], [54312] , [54321] at which point i=4 so the for loop test fails and your array is sorted . . . Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to look up the Internet for the bubblesort algorithm.

In here:

```
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      for(j=1;j<n;j++)
      {
        if(a[i]>a[j])
        {
          p=a[j];
          a[j]=a[i];
          a[i]=p;
        }
      }
    }
```

<strike>In this, the 2nd iteration of the first `for` doesn't consider `a[0]` so you're passing through relevant numbers.</strike>

Nevermind this. Assume that `a[j]` is the "moving" element that you want to sort (biggest to lower), you should start the second loop with `j=0` so that all elements are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within your nested loops. You are implementing a swap but not considering all of the elements in the array. To fix this, change the following:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < n; i++ ) {
  for ( j = 1; j < n; j++ ) {
```

... to:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < n; i++ ) {
  for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
```

... and these two loops will sort your array in O(n^2) time. You can do better if you implement other sorting algorithms (and do so properly), I would suggest optimizing your code. Consider this implementation of a bubble sort:

```
bool swapped;

do {
  swapped = false;

  for ( int i = 0; i < ( n - 1 ); i++ ) {
    if ( a[ i ] > a[ i + 1 ] ) {
      int const temp = a[ i ];

      a[ i ] = a[ i + 1 ];
      a[ i + 1 ] = temp;

      swapped = true;
    }
  }
} while ( swapped == true );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<n;j++)
  {
   if (j != i){
    if(a[i]>a[j])
    {
      p=a[j];
      a[j]=a[i];
      a[i]=p;
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are familiar with the concept of recursion then I would recommand you the quicksort algorithm , here's how it works :

```
int qsort(int arr[] ,int lenght)
{
        int pivot , i = 0 , l = lenght - 1;
        const int MIN = 0 , MAX = l;
        if(lenght < 2)
                return;
        srand(time(NULL));
        pivot = arr[(rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN];
        while(i < l)
        {
                while(arr[i] < pivot)
                        i++;
                while(arr[l] > pivot)
                        l--;
                swap(arr , i , l);
        }
        qsort(arr , i);
        qsort(&arr[i + 1] , lenght - 1 - i);
}       
int swap(int arr[] , int elem1 , int elem2)
{
        int temp;
        temp = arr[elem1];
        arr[elem1] = arr[elem2];
        arr[elem2] = temp;
}
```

but be careful because this only works if every element of the given array is unique .

Answer (score 0):

Just a rectification in your code!

According to comparision condition `(a[i] > a[j])`, your code perform swapping if inner loop's `j` indexed elements are smaller then outer loop's `i` indexed element in array. And you start your inner loop from `j = 1` so it doesn't checks and short 0<sup>th</sup> indexed element So `a[0]` remains unsorted.

```
  if(a[i] > a[j])

  when i = 0           

  if(a[0] > a[j]) == never true as a[0] is smallest element and j start with 1
```

You just need to start inner loop from `j = 0` to make it work correctly.

```
 for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
  //     ^ its 0 not 1
```

And here your code working: @[codepade](http://codepad.org/XJyPUJT6)

**Note** as you starts with `j = 0` then

```
  if(a[i] > a[0]) becomes true when i > 0
```

Comment: If one down-vote please left a comment Its logical problem and I am not very good at logic I just try to understand and bug the code. Let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to initializing `j` to `i+1` is sufficient to fix the program.  In addition, the code as written will sort an *ascending*, not *descending* order.

The code is attempting to perform a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).  The principle at work here is that we select the minimum element from the array, put it in the `0`th slot, then select the minimum of the *remainder*.  The algorithm as implemented is selecting the minimum from the *entire* list, which means that elements that were already correctly placed are being removed and put back in the wrong location.

Comment: But this small rectification in OP code causes Undefined behavior!! Check why **?** a question to you :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, you may be referring to the fact that when `i == n - 1`, then `j` will get initialized to `n`, but this is not undefined behavior -- no memory at that position is ever accessed because the loop guard will kick out.  Unless there's something else I missed.